# How to return mulitple columns in a WHERE clause CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My stored procedure accepts parameters and one of them is `@SearchBy` which can contain a couple of different values like `IISAppPool`, `ScheduledTask`, `WindowsService`, `COM+`, `ServiceAccount`, etc like shown in my `CASE statement` below.

Depending on what the value is it will go and look for that value in the value's corresponding column.

`sComponentType` will always contain `IIS_APP_POOL`, `SCHED_TASK`, `WIN_SERVICE` or `COM_PLUS` irrespective of what `@SearchBy` is.

I am struggling with my where clause, it needs a `CASE` statement.

The following is working fine.

```
WHERE
     sDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
     AND
          CASE @SearchBy
               WHEN 'IISAppPool' THEN sComponentName
               WHEN 'ScheduledTask' THEN sComponentName
               WHEN 'WindowsService' THEN sComponentName
               WHEN 'COM+' THEN sComponentName
               WHEN 'ServiceAccount' THEN sServiceAccount
               WHEN 'Server' THEN sServerName
               WHEN 'IMCCReference' THEN sIMCCReference
               WHEN 'User' THEN sManager
          END LIKE('%' + @SearchCriteria + '%')
```

What I am looking for is something like:

```
WHERE
     sDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
     AND
          CASE @SearchBy
               WHEN 'IISAppPool' THEN sComponentName AND sComponentType = 'IIS_APP_POOL'
               WHEN 'ScheduledTask' THEN sComponentName AND sComponentType = 'SCHED_TASK'
               WHEN 'WindowsService' THEN sComponentName AND sComponentType = 'WIN_SERVICE'
               WHEN 'COM+' THEN sComponentName AND sComponentType = 'COM_PLUS'
               WHEN 'ServiceAccount' THEN sServiceAccount
               WHEN 'Server' THEN sServerName
               WHEN 'IMCCReference' THEN sIMCCReference
               WHEN 'User' THEN sManager
          END LIKE('%' + @SearchCriteria + '%')
```

I know this is not possible so I tried the following in addition to what I have above but I just don't know how to write the code if `@SearchBy` is not an app pool, scheduled task, windows service or COM+ component:

```
AND
     sComponentType =
          CASE @SearchBy
               WHEN 'IISAppPool' THEN 'IIS_APP_POOL'
               WHEN 'ScheduledTask' THEN 'SCHED_TASK'
               WHEN 'WindowsService' THEN 'WIN_SERVICE'
               WHEN 'COM+' THEN 'COM_PLUS'
          END
```

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not use a searched case statement rather than a simple case statement? e.g.

```
AND
      CASE 
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'IISAppPool' AND sComponentType = 'IIS_APP_POOL' THEN sComponentName 
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'ScheduledTask' AND sComponentType = 'SCHED_TASK' THEN sComponentName
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'WindowsService' AND sComponentType = 'WIN_SERVICE' THEN sComponentName
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'COM+' AND sComponentType = 'COM_PLUS' THEN sComponentName
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'ServiceAccount' THEN sServiceAccount
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'Server' THEN sServerName
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'IMCCReference' THEN sIMCCReference
           WHEN @SearchBy = 'User' THEN sManager
      END LIKE('%' + @SearchCriteria + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
sComponentType =
      CASE @SearchBy
           WHEN 'IISAppPool' THEN 'IIS_APP_POOL'
           WHEN 'ScheduledTask' THEN 'SCHED_TASK'
           WHEN 'WindowsService' THEN 'WIN_SERVICE'
           WHEN 'COM+' THEN 'COM_PLUS'
           ELSE sComponentType
      END
```

Assuming sComponentType is not null

Comment: Thanks this worked as well, but I am going to go with GarethD, the code is less.